# Target Machine actively refusing connection, tried iisreset and netstat to view the problem?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm familiarizing myself with a package based on mongodb.driver, through this package you don't have to deal with bson documents and it has built in support for relationships.

The predicament I found myself in is during initialization of the DB.

https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities

The way the initialization it is by calling the DB class with a hostname and port number:

```
new DB("bookshop", "localhost" "27017");
```

The error that I keep getting is the machine has chosen to actively refuse the connections even if I change the port number to say 8080

I had looked through the netstat to see if the port/address is being used by another program but it hadn't been. Then I tried to reset IIS but that didn't work either.

The link I have attached has a friendly wiki that explains how to use the entity extension.

Comment: The error means that service you are trying to connect to is not running

Comment: @It'satrap There is an example of how to do it in the wiki using a console app, i have actively copied that whole project so now i know if it worked for them then that means there's something on my end stopping it. I have turned off all my firewalls too

Comment: it's not about the project. Mongo service should be running and available for others to connect to where you are running your project from.

Comment: @It'satrap that makes sense, i thought it was automatically handled by the extension my bad, yeah i never initialised mongo anywhere to be honest  this is the db.cs but i think you're right https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/master/MongoDB.Entities/DB.cs

Comment: @Darman i'm the author of MongoDB.Entities. like 'It's a trap' said, your mongodb service is not running properly. check [this guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) to install and configure the server service correctly. and here's a sample [mongodb.cfg](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/KiwilinkCRM/blob/master/Kiwilink-API/Mongo/mongod.cfg) to get you started. make sure those folders are created before starting the mongodb service. let me know if you need further help.